# Add attachment to all selected items in Outlook 2016 with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, outlook-2016

I aim to add an attachment to every item that is currently selected in Outlook 2016. My idea is to call `Attachments.Add` in a loop on each item in the current selection.

In my Drafts folder, I have three drafts with the subjects:

- Draft Test 3
- Draft Test 2
- Draft Test 1

Because of the environment that I am in, I cannot use C#. I am using VBA instead. I ran all the test code by clicking **Developer** > **Macros** > **[sub name]** in the Outlook 2016 ribbon.

I started with this:

```
Sub AddTestTxtToSelection1()
    Dim i As Long
    With Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
            .Item(i).Attachments.Add "C:\Full\Path\To\Test.txt", olByValue, 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, `Test.txt` was only attached to Draft Test 3 although all three drafts were selected. I thought that I might be iterating through the selection incorrectly, so I tried this:

```
Sub AddTestTxtToSelection2()
    For Each objMessage In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        objMessage.Attachments.Add "C:\Full\Path\To\Test.txt", olByValue, 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Again, although all three drafts were selected, `Test.txt` was only attached to Draft Test 3. In the example code in [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff868001(v=office.16).aspx), `Application.ActiveExplorer` and its `Selection` property are stored in separate variables. I thought that that might have been what was missing, so I wrote this:

```
Sub AddTestTxtToSelection3()
    Dim myOlExp As Explorer
    Dim myOlSel As Selection
    Set myOlExp = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set myOlSel = myOlExp.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To myOlSel.Count
        myOlSel.Item(i).Attachments.Add "C:\Full\Path\To\Test.txt", olByValue, 1
    Next
End Sub
```

The behavior was identical to that of the first two tests. Finally, it occurred to me that the problem might be with modifying the drafts as I was looping over them. I then wrote this code, which stores the `EntryID` properties of the selected items in a separate string array before looping over them:

```
Sub AddTestTxtToSelection4()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strEntryID As Variant
    Dim namespaceMAPI As NameSpace
    Dim objMessage As Object
    Dim selected() As String
    ' Copy the current selection into an array of EntryID strings.
    ReDim selected(1 To Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count) As String
    For i = 1 To Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Count
        selected(i) = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(i).EntryID
    Next
    ' Retrieve each item from its EntryID string.
    Set namespaceMAPI = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    namespaceMAPI.Logon
    For Each strEntryID In selected
        Set objMessage = namespaceMAPI.GetItemFromID(strEntryID)
        objMessage.Attachments.Add "C:\Full\Path\To\Test.txt", olByValue, 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Again, only Draft Test 3 had `Test.txt` attached after running this code. I thought that Outlook might be having trouble attaching the same file to multiple drafts, so I modified the last test to attach a different file to each draft. Only Draft Test 3 had an attachment after it was executed. Even if I swap out `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection` for `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items`, still only the first draft gets an attachment.

Why can't Outlook attach a file to more than one mail item at a time? Is there a workaround?

Comment: If you did this manually there would be a prompt asking if you wanted to save. Throw in a `.Save` after the `Add`.

Comment: @niton D'oh. That worked. If you put that in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certain actions require a `.Save`.

There is likely a correlation with actions that require a save when done manually. In this case if you were to manually attach a file then close the draft you would be asked if the draft should be saved.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted @niton's answer, but here is my code after adding `.Save`:

```
' Based on AddTestTxtToSelection2
Sub AddTestTxtToSelection5()
    For Each objMessage In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        objMessage.Attachments.Add "C:\Full\Path\To\Test.txt", olByValue, 1
        objMessage.Save ' This line was added.
    Next
End Sub
```

The attachments get added to every selected message now.